# What would be the easiest way to do a list of skills on a page that open in a popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, popup

I'm trying to list a bunch of skills on my website and have each of them open in a pop-up on click to give a little more info.
Basically, I want it to look like this, **not as a button**.
[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irUNA.png)

I've tried some codes from the internet but they either don't work or break my Wordpress theme.

The closest I've gotten was with this piece of code:

["Example code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_script)"

Answer (score 0):

To open a link in a new tab as a popup, the easiest way is to :

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#">Link</a>
```

target="_blank" is the attribute to have a link open in a new tab.

Answer (score -1):

If these articles are in an array, you can return this array and create an element from each article in it and assign a click event to this element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).